# Floatable div for Google Maps streetview?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking for a floatable `div` for Google Maps Street View? I can move it around the page/close it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use [jQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable). Note that you'd want to use a [handle](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle) since the DOM events related to dragging (probably) don't propagate outside of an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) it has boxes like what you are asking for.